# Google Maps iOS SDK mylocation button not showing

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I enabled **myLocation** and **myLocationButton**,
but it not showing on my view.
And I try log `_mapView.myLocation` it's `nil`.

I need to showing **myLocation** dot and **myLocationButton**.
Have some one can help me, thanks!

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import "Reachability.h"

@interface ViewController ()<GMSMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager * locationManager;
    CLLocation *currentLocations;
    Reachability * udnReach;
};

@property (strong,nonatomic) GMSMapView * mapView;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSDictionary * dic;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSTimer * updatetimer;


@end

@implementation ViewController {
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    locationManager =[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    locationManager.delegate =self;
    if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
        [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    _mapView.delegate = self;
    _mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    _mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    //Map

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
                                                            longitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude
                                                                 zoom:16];
    _mapView= [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(networkStatusChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
    udnReach=[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"google.com"];
    //    udnReach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [udnReach startNotifier];

    [self updatebike];
     self.view = self.mapView;
    NSLog(@"User's location: %@", _mapView.myLocation);
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find to show button and get userlocation

```
// Rather than setting -myLocationEnabled to YES directly,
// call this method:

- (void)enableMyLocation
{
    CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
        [self requestLocationAuthorization];
    else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted)
        return; // we weren't allowed to show the user's location so don't enable
    else
        [self.view setMyLocationEnabled:YES];
}

// Ask the CLLocationManager for location authorization,
// and be sure to retain the manager somewhere on the class

- (void)requestLocationAuthorization
{
    _locationAuthorizationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    _locationAuthorizationManager.delegate = self;

    [_locationAuthorizationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}

// Handle the authorization callback. This is usually
// called on a background thread so go back to main.

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    if (status != kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(enableMyLocation) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:[NSThread isMainThread]];

        _locationAuthorizationManager.delegate = nil;
        _locationAuthorizationManager = nil;
    }
}
```